# How to bind the selection of the NSTableView to the NSArrayController

Tags: cocoa, binding, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I just want to be able to use the the methods of the nsarraycontroller called remove: and add:

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Select the NSTableView. If the inspector window's title shows Scroll View, you need to click the table view again to select it.
2. In the bindings tab, connect the `Selection Indexes` binding to the Array Controller's `selectionIndexes` controller key. This is similar to binding the content to the array controller, except that you don't use the arrangedObjects key.

Comment: Hah, you're right. Don't no what i made yesterday. Now it works.